# c/c++ program for ffmpeg command line

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I want to find the corresponding c/c++ program for the ffmpeg command line:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -an -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 outfile.h264
```

which convert a sample.mp4 file to outfile.h264, and

```
ffplay outfile.h264
```

What I am doing is to combine the ffmpeg program with my udp socket program to do a real-time video transmission. beacause it is 'real-time', so I want to find the ffmpeg program cut it at the frame encoding step instead of writing the frames into output file, and send frame by frame and also read frame by frame at the server side.

My questions are:

1.What c/c++ program is actually running when I use the above command line?

2.where can i find the c/c++ program?

Comment: Google "ffmpeg source code"?

Comment: Got so many source code, dont know use which one.....

Comment: 0. figure out how to "google" better 1. goto git repo.  2. locate main() ... usually in main.c  3. find the option parsing section  4. follow the variable or function that corresponds to the option you are looking for 5. continue tracking it down.

Answer (score 2):

1. `ffmpeg` is running. Same as any other program, there's an actual file on "the path" called `ffmpeg`. Use `which ffmpeg` or `where ffmpeg` to find it. On the systems at my university it is in `/usr/pkg/bin/ffmpeg`, but `/usr/bin/ffmpeg` is probably more typical.
2. The program itself *is* the `ffmpeg` file. If you mean the source code for the program, that is most likely not installed on your computer - you'll need to download it from somewhere (such as from the official FFmpeg website).

Note that FFmpeg is both a program and a set of libraries (`libavformat`, `libavcodec`, `libavutil`, etc). Most of the work is done in the libraries; the `ffmpeg` program itself just glues them together depending on the command line options.

As such, a more useful approach might be to learn how to use `libavformat` and `libavcodec` (and whichever other FFmpeg libraries) to do what you want. The documentation at http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html doesn't seem to go into much detail; you might want to search for some tutorials.

Comment: Thank you immibis, I have already installed ffmepg , thats why i can run the command line. And i have investigated the encoding/decoding example program source code, http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding-example_8c-source.html , but in that code, it encode artificial frames and what i want is let the program fetch my own video file.

Comment: @Yoohoo to *read* a video file (or stream), you probably want to find a *de*coding example.